# C++ code crashing when trying to pass struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, gtk

I have this struct:

```
struct dat {
    std::string name;
};
```

When the following code is run, my program crashes:

```
dat* x = (struct dat*)malloc(sizeof(struct dat));
x->name = str;
g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (func), &x);
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` on a C++ class with a C++ class inside it?

Comment: In addition to the `malloc` issue. Just ask: is `x` still in scope when the signal handler is invoked? The memory allocated will be available after `x` is out of scope, but the variable `x` is in the stack and will be destroyed when reaching the end of the scope, loosing the reference. If the handler is called later in a loop event the content of that reference can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `malloc` in C++.

If you need a variable to have dynamic storage duration, use `new` and `delete` instead. In short, `malloc` will **not** call any constructors, whereas `new` will. The fact that the `std::string` constructor is not being called is probably the cause of your crash.

In many cases though, automatic storage duration will suffice, and you can write, simply:

`dat foo;`

and pass that instance *by reference* to your functions.

Comment: Nope, not even if you want dynamic storage duration. We have `std::make_unique` now.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: We can agree to disagree. Your not wanting to use `new` and `delete` smacks of pure unbridled dogmatism.

Comment: While I'll agree naked `new`'s should be avoided just always blindingly following *don't use `new`* also isn't the way.

Comment: Well, `new` shouldn't be exposed to beginners.

Comment: @Bathsheba: No need to be rude. "If you need a variable to have dynamic storage duration, use `new` and `delete` instead" is certainly no less sure of itself than my suggestion.